# Converting csv to Rdata

Tags: r

I am a novice in R STUDIO and I am trying to convert a CSV file into an Rdata (.rds) format. Can someone help me out regarding this?

I have searched online and so far the answers I have found does not match what I need.

Comment: .rdata & .rds are two different formats. Which do you really want? And saying the answers you've found so far don't match what you need isn't going to help others suss out what you actually need. Try describing what you've found, what you've tried so far, & where you are facing problems.

Comment: I am following this page: https://www.datascience.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-shiny-and-leaflet-for-interactive-mapping and he talks about both .rdata and .rds files so I assumed that they were both the same.

I tried to look for an online converter, however I couldn't find one that matched either of those formats.

I also tried just changing the extension directly on my Mac from csv to rds/rdata but this caused an error when trying to open the file.

Comment: I think I was confusing myself I am very new to R so the articles you linked are much better laid out and easier for me to follow.

Thank you for your help.